# BeautifulSoup only returning one result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

I have some html laid out like this

```
<div class="news-a">

 <article>
  <header>
   <h2>
     <a>destination 1</a>
   </h2>
  </header>
 </article>

 <article>
  <header>
   <h2>
     <a>destination 2</a>
   </h2>
  </header>
 </article>

 <article>
  <header>
   <h2>
     <a>destination 3</a>
   </h2>
  </header>
 </article>

</div>
```

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to return all of the destination names, so I have targeted the div name of "news-a" because I know there is only one of these on the site. I have my scraper code as so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('url')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

destinations = soup.find(class_='news-a')

for destination in destinations.find_all('h2'):
    print(destination.text)
```

But this only returns the first result of "destination 1" when used with the live url

[Sample of inspect code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBWks.png)

Comment: I have stated this in ```find_all('h2')``` but it is only returning one result

Comment: Works for me with the fragment example you posted.

Comment: With the live sample, it seems to only show one result, can give a HTML snippet of the live sample

Comment: Maybe show us what `print(destinations)` looks like, if it is too big.

Comment: Only shows one result which is the first result ```Con Dao``` I have added an image snippet of the live html

Comment: @BradSolomon not exactly sure what you mean only returns one location in the first place, there is more than 1 location displayed in the list of locations on that page you've now given? Please elaborate, the code above shows the basics of what the HTML says on the page you've linked

Comment: I just *scraped* the page using your code and it printed twenty-one lines - the first is more like a description and the rest are locations.

Comment: Using the link presented above? I am not sure why I am only receiving one result in my terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one. More concise with desired output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.travelindicator.com/destinations?page=1').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".news-a h2 a"):
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
Con Dao
Kuwait City
Funafuti
Saint Helier
Mount Kailash
Sunny Beach
Krakow
Azores
Alsace
Qaqortoq
Salt Lake City
Valkenburg
Daegu
Lviv
São Luís
Abidjan
Lampedusa
Lecce
Norfolk Island
Petra
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, perfect! It definitely makes more sense to me

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your simplified example is drastically different from the HTML in the link that you originally posted and then deleted.

Try this instead, using your travelindicator.com link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.travelindicator.com/destinations?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
locs = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' 
                     and tag.get('href').startswith('locations')
                     and tag.has_attr('title')
                     and not tag.has_attr('style'))

for loc in locs:
    # `locs` is now a Python list of `a` tags, each with an href
    #     and title attribute
    if loc.get('title').startswith('Travel ideas'):
        print(loc.text)
Con Dao
Kuwait City
Funafuti
Saint Helier
Mount Kailash
Sunny Beach
Krakow
Azores
Alsace
Qaqortoq
Salt Lake City
Valkenburg
Daegu
Lviv
São Luís
Abidjan
Lampedusa
Lecce
Norfolk Island
Petra
```

**More on why your original method was giving you trouble:**

In that actual link, when you use

```
dest = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'news-a'})
```

this tag only has one `h2` attribute of the type you're looking for.  You need to `find_all` `<h2>` tags in `soup.`

To see this, try `print(dest.prettify())`.  You'll notice that none of your desired city results are included in this nested structure.  Keep in mind that `find` finds only the first result.  If you're familiar with the concept of the [HTML document tree](http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weekfour/document-tree.html), the other `div` ("news-a") are siblings, not children, of your result here.

Comment: I removed the second snippet fro confusion as that one wasn't working the right way around. I understand the above but what I don't understand is the issue in selecting the h2, there are multiple h2s within the class of ```"news-a"``` why can't these be used to select the locations? Thanks either way that's really helped